# Streamlit: Why does updating the session_state with form data require submitting the form twice?

Tags: python, forms, session-state, streamlit

I appear to fundamentally misunderstand how Streamlit's forms and `session_state` variable work. Form data is not inserted into the `session_state` upon submit. However, submitting a second time inserts the data. Updating `session_state` values always requires submitting the form 2 times.

I'd like to know

1. if this is expected behavior
2. if I'm making a mistake
3. if there is a workaround that allows immediate `session_state` updates on submit

**EXAMPLE 1:**

```py
import streamlit as st

# View all key:value pairs in the session state
s = []
for k, v in st.session_state.items():
    s.append(f"{k}: {v}")
st.write(s)

# Define the form
with st.form("my_form"):
    st.session_state['name'] = st.text_input("Name")
    st.form_submit_button("Submit")
```

When the page loads, the session state is empty: `[]`
[image]

After submitting the form once, the session_state contains `"name: "`. The key has been added, but not the value.
[image]

After pressing `Submit` a second time, the session_state now contains `"name: Chris"`
[image]

**EXAMPLE 2:** Using a callback function

```py
import streamlit as st

# View all key:value pairs in the session state
s = []
for k, v in st.session_state.items():
    s.append(f"{k}: {v}")
st.write(s)

# Define the form
with st.form("my_form"):
    def update():
        st.session_state['name'] = name

    name = st.text_input("Name")
    st.form_submit_button("Submit", on_click=update)
```

When the page loads, the session state is empty: `[]`
[image]

After submitting the form once, the session_state contains `"name: "`. The key has been added, but not the value.
[image]

After pressing `Submit` a second time, the session_state now contains `"name: Chris"`
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The critical part to think about is: where are you writing session state values relative to where the widget is? In particular, you are accessing/displaying session state values *before* the widget.

Try this to see what's happening a bit clearer:

```py
import streamlit as st

st.write(st.session_state)

with st.form('my_form'):
    st.session_state.A = st.text_input('A')
    st.text_input('B', key='B')
    st.form_submit_button('Submit')

st.write(st.session_state)
```

You will note for widget A that session state does not update until after the widget. If you want to access data for widget A *before* widget A, then you end up with your "double submit" problem.

For widget B, you can see that session state is correct right away, even when accessed before the widget.

#### What is happening?

For a widget (outside of form), when a user makes a change:

1. User enters a new value
2. Session state associated to the widget's key is updated
3. The page reloads
4. The output of the widget function shows the new value

If you have the output of a widget assign a value to session state instead of setting the key for the widget directly, then that output data cannot be updated until the widget function is executed again and can output that new value.

With a form, the same logic applies except that the new value is not registered until the submit button is clicked.

#### Solutions

1. You can assign a key to a widget directly so that the value is update upon the change, before the page loads.
2. (Or) You can make sure to not access widget data before the widget.

   - If needed you can use containers to allow you to have the widget logically first in the script but displayed later in the page.

Comment: So then it appears that interacting with the form submission button does not reload the page like interacting with a non-form widget would.

Comment: Interacting with a form submission button *does* reload the page, same as interacting with a non-form widget. Interacting with a widget inside of a form does not reload the page.

Comment: I think I get it. It's the ASSIGNMENT of widget A that is occurring after the initial printing of st.session_state. In any case, the 'key' parameter of the widget allows implicit insertion into the session state, and is the more correct way to store form values. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, by using a the `key` keyword in a widget, the value is updated before the page is rerun. When you get the value as an output of the widget function (as in `st.session_state.A = st.text_input('A')`) then the new information doesn't get into session state until that line is executed on the rerun. Note: If you change a widget inside a form and then reload the page from something *other* than the form submit button, the widget inside the form will not update session state yet, regardless of using the key inside or outside that widget function).